# dispatch loadstate action inside of useeffect after page load error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, redux, redux-saga

i have cookie based authentication so i need call api to check for authentication on each page load.also i am using redux to maintain a global auth state like below

```
const initialState = {
  user: {},
  isLoading: false,
  error: null,
  isTeacher: false,
  isModerator: false,
  isStudent: false,
};
```

on each refresh inside of useeffect of app page

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_USER" });
  }, []);
```

this is giving me error. i want to initialize the state on login before the page renders.

```
const isAuthenticated =
    select.isTeacher || select.isStudent || select.isModerator;
 <Router>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={!isAuthenticated ? <Landing /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
          />
          <Route
            path="/home"
            element={isAuthenticated ? <Home /> : <Navigate to="/" />}
          ></Route>
          <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
```

the dispatch call inside of useeffect is giving me error like i cannot use a hook inside of another hook.

Comment: Can you please copy-paste the whole exact error here?

Comment: Don't put `useEffect` inside of another `useEffect`, because if I understand your description correctly, this is what you're doing and also what the error is complaining about.

Comment: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks, can you also please show us more of your app page code? In what scope is the useEffect located, what other hooks are used etc.

Comment: i have stored jwt token inside cookie and i need to send this token to backend on page load. to change the state what will solve this problem?